# Issues with cross validation Error using naiveFolds using Rstudio

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am trying to figure out crossvalidationError using naiveFolds.

```
naiveBayes_fold = function(fold, features, target, laplace = 0) {
  train = features[-fold,]
  validation = features[fold,]
  train_labels = target[-fold]
  validation_labels = target[fold]
  NaiveBayes_model = naiveBayes(train, train_labels, laplace = laplace)
  validation_preds = predict(NaiveBayes_model, validation)
  t= table(validation_labels, validation_preds)
  FPR = t[1,2] / (t[1,2] + t[1,1])
  FNR = t[2,1] / (t[2,1] + t[2,2])
  return (c("FPR" = FPR, "FNR" = FNR))
}

crossValidationError = function(features, target, laplace = 0, n_folds) {
  folds = createFolds(target, k = n_folds)
  errors = sapply(folds, naiveBayes_fold, features = features, target = target, laplace = laplace)
  return(rowMeans(errors))
}
```

When I run this following code,

```
crossValidationError(AdultSet_n, dt_coded, 0, 5)
```

I get an error saying `(Error in table(y) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements)`
To explain briefly for AdultSet_n, it is a data.frame with 30162 obs. of  105 variables and it has all numeric features. For dt_coded, it is also a data.frame with 30162 obs. of  105 variables but it has all int features. The reason why I get the error is because of different features? I also have a similar issue with running errors with FPR (False Positive Rate) and FNR (False Negative Rate). Here is the code.

```
errors = crossValidationError(features = AdultSet_n, target = dt_coded, n_folds=5)
```

Let me know what is wrong with this. Thank you in advance.